# How to deserialize xml nodes with a different name into a list

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I want to deserialize an xml file using c#.

the file has this form:

```
<parent>
   <TotProd Name="Total Produce Kwh">
       <Time value="00:00:00">10</Time>
       <Time value="00:30:00">10</Time>
        ............ 
   </TotProd>
   <ProdToNet Name="Produce to Net (iec)">
       <Time value="00:00:00">10</Time>
       <Time value="00:30:00">10</Time>
        ...........
   </ProdToNet> .....
</parent>
```

I want to deserialize all child elements of `parent` into a `List<Myclass>` with `TotProd/ProdToNet` as a property of `Myclass`.

How can i do this.

Comment: Provide your class details also..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a common class for both elements, if they have the same structure:

```
public class Time{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value {get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text {get;set;} // this will hold the innerText value ("10") of <Time>
}

public class Prod{

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Time")]
    public List<Time> Time {get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("parent")]
public class Parent{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ProdToNet", Type=typeof(Prod))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName="TotProd", Type=typeof(Prod))]
    public List<Prod> {get; set;}
}
```

UPDATE:
The `Time:value` seems like a TimeSpan duration object, so it can be presented as:

```
public class Time{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan _duration;

    [XmlAttribute(DataType = "duration")]
    public string value
        get
        {
            return XmlConvert.ToString(this._duration);
        }

        set
        {
            this._duration = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I also had to add XmlChoiceIdentifier attribute as displayed here "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute.aspx". it would be nice if it was possible to deserialize all child elements to a list even without know the name of the elements in advance.

Comment: You can use a [XmlAnyElement] attribute to handle all elements without knowing their names, and then just deserialize them manually: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlanyelements